# How to append dom with a item count

Tags: jquery

I have to insert dom object with a count of times like `$('ul').append('<li>',5); //5 times`

I know how to do that with for loop but i am looking elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5],function(i){$('ul').append('<li>',i+1);});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this custom plugin [`.duplicate()`](http://jqueryminute.com/duplicate-and-clone-elements-multiple-times/)

suppose you want to clone 5 li of a ul

#### HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
 <li> I am the Original <code>li</code> </li>
</ul>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('li').duplicate(5).appendTo('#myList');
```

here how you extend this plugin

```
$.fn.duplicate = function(count, cloneEvents) {
    var tmp = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        $.merge( tmp, this.clone( cloneEvents ).get() );
    }
    return this.pushStack( tmp );
};
```

[`Working Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/627re/)